# Swap text before and after "=" in properties file

Tags: text-editing, text

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

Suppose I have properties file:

1=10

2=BS.30

3=BS.20A

Before "=" are numbers, but after "=" has any text(without spaces)

I want to swap text before and after "=".

So the result must be:

10=1

BS.30=2

BS.20A=3

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `query-replace-regexp` which is bound to the key sequence <kbd>M-%</kbd>.

Use `^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)$` as regular expression and `\2=\1` as replacement text.

- the leading `^` stands for the empty string at the beginning of line (the match is anchored at the beginning of line)
- the escaped parentheses `\(\)` delimit groups which you can refer to in the replacement string
- `[^=]*` means any number of characters that are not the equal sign
- `=` just stands for itself
- `.*` are any characters
- `$` at  the end of the regular expression matches the empty string at the end of line (it anchors the regexp there)

Comment: Emacs is COOL!!! It's amazing.

Comment: this also work:  ^\\(.*\\)=\\(.*\\)$